# linker error problem

Tags: c++

**Program:**

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    int a[5] = {4,5,9,1,2};

    int i,j,temp;
    cout<<"Assending sorting: "<<endl;

    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
       temp = a[i];
       if(a[i]<a[i-1])
       {
           temp = a[i-1];
           a[i-1] = a[i];
          a[i] = temp;
       }
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
error LNK2005: _main already defined in assen test.obj  
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\my Project\sorting\binary
search\main.obj

error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\my Project\sorting\Debug\binary 
search.exe
```

From my point of view, the program should work OK, but i don't understand the linker error. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: yes i know, i tried to format the above line.. but i failed .. let me do it again..

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear - its says that somewhere you have another `main` defined. So do a search for it in your project, and consign the sucker to history and it should work...

Comment: ah but main is the only one in this project...how  and where main is defined...

Comment: well, i maked two project in same workspace .. and both project have their main() ... i think this should not create problem of main() because both projects are differents and have their own work..

Comment: surely visual studio has a search across all files in projects feature - use it! It may be revealing... here is a hint, what goes into `test.obj`

Comment: @nim: well i used sreach tool.. but i just find only one main() .. there is not any other main()

Comment: what is `assen test.obj`? have a look at the source for this object, the problem is there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you seem to have declared two functions with the name `main` in your code, possibly in another .c/.cpp file.

Comment: @constantinis : yes thanks now i understand .. and i found two main() function...

Comment: is my program right.. its not giving me output except the cout  statement... why

Comment: @Miss: Your program works right, you gave only the instruction to output the one line. Add additional 'cout <<' as required.